# Automatizing while loop: getting rid of the user input

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

Right now I have a big while loop that runs until the user says to add no more data. Inside the loop, I ask the user for three inputs: name of the file (there are four possible files), condition1, and condition2 (each with two possible answers).
Inside of the loop I define condition3 and condition4 (again each with two possible options) based on the name of the file.
From the text file, I create a dataframe.
And different actions are made based on the 4 conditions.

In the end, after the user enters all the possible combinations I get 16 .csv files (4 files/answers times 4 possible answers) with
`df2.to_csv(f"{condition1}_{condition2}_{condition3}_{condition4}.csv")`
How can I automatize the process so that I do not need the user inputs and just automatically get 16 files?

Comment: You have left out a *lot* of detail.

Comment: This seems like you just need nested loops.  `for filename in ...:` / `for condition1 in ...:` / `for condition2 in ...`